# Get last modified time of a CSS file in WordPress from header.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to append the last modified time of the CSS file of my theme to the stylesheet URL.

I tried using the following code but it does not set any value for `v`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://the-website.com/wp-content/themes/unique/style.css?v=<?php echo filemtime('style.css'); ?>" />
```

The `style.css` file exists in the same directory as my `header.php` so this should have worked and appended the `filemtime()` value but it doesn't. Could anyone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should enqueue you stylesheet with wp_enqueue in your functions - other than that, you should also use `filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css');`

Comment: Thanks @Stender is there any particular reason for using `get_stylesheet_directory()` if `style.css` exists in same directory as `header.php`?

Comment: I guess it needs the absolute path - else it will look in `https://the-website.com/style.css` which doesn't exist? not exactly sure

Comment: Thanks @Stender. :) Just one more question. Is there any particular advantage of using `wp_enqueue` instead of directly linking to CSS and JavaScript files in the header and footer files?

Comment: basically It ensures that all of your plugin and your theme doesn't overwrite eachothers stylesheets. - plus you can control the dependancies etc.

Comment: If you have two plugins that use the same stylesheet and the both use the same wp_enqueue_style handle then Wordpress will only add the stylesheet on the page once. When you add things to wp_enqueue_style it adds your styles to a list of stylesheets it needs to add on the page when it is loaded. If a handle already exists it will not add a new stylesheet to this list.

Comment: Another good feature of the wp_enqueue_style function is the 3rd parameter $deps, this is dependencies, if you pass an array of stylesheet handles it means this stylesheet will not be added to the page until all of these handles are added.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stender. :)

Comment: _“The style.css file exists in the same directory as my header.php so this should have worked”_ - no it should not, because you are not calling header.php in your browser directly from the path where it is located, but the index.php includes this file at some point. So the _working directory_ of your script is not that which contains the header.php in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe So this means that if a file `index.php` is located in different directory from `header.php` it will not be able to locate `style.css` when someone visit `index.php`?

Comment: No, of course it does not mean that, not at all. It just means that you need to specify the path correctly …

Comment: If it were only about the info, the info could also be packed into the CSS. If you're working with Gulp.js, here's an example: https://gist.github.com/jolution/9b2abbd53a326b8f1b2a13403f12e16f#file-gulpfile-js-L293

Here @lastmodified is replaced by lastmodified and date in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the code below to get filetime of CSS file.

```
$path = get_template_directory().'/style.css';

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://the-website.com/wp-content/themes/unique/style.css?v=<?php echo filemtime($path); ?>" />
```